# Compile error: Syntax Error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, compile, syntax

I cannot find a solution for this error, I am a beginner in Excel Macro and am trying to use this code to create a dropdown menu that autofills like a google search from Data Validation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code that you expect people to look at (and potentially debug for you). You should post the actual code in your question and make sure it is appropriately [formatted](https://superuser.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted row is a fragment of a URL. If this is supposed to be a comment, then you need to start the row with an apostrophe sign `'` or hit backspace at the beginning of the row, so it gets reunited with the text in the row above.

With all due respect, but if something like that throws you, how do you expect to deal with real issues in the code? You may want to spend some time on learning the basics of VBA before you embarge on a project with this kind of complexity.